# I need to find the prime numbers from 1 to 300 using C. I am using the following code

Tags: c

[image: I have added a image for my code]
I know that there is mistake in second for loop but I am not able to figure out. I think after if the continue will take it to to for loop if a%i ==0 and if a%i!=0 than it should print a which would be an prime number , but instead it is printing all the numbers from 2 to 300. Please help!!

Comment: Please copy/paste the code as text, into the question.

Comment: You are using wrong algorithm to check for prime.

Comment: Note the *as text* bit of @WeatherVane's comment (though I suppose an image is better than nothing).

Comment: Your inner loop has no effect. Try something simpler, like code to print all the odd numbers from 1 to 10.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve] example.

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` and `break` instructions both instruct the inner `i` loop. So whatever happens, your code prints every value of `a` in the outer loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, i;
    for (a=1; a<=300; a++) {
        for (i=2; i<a; i++) {           // changed from the clumsy i<=a-1
            if (a % i == 0)
                break;                  // end loop if i is a divisor
        }
        if (i == a)                     // if the loop completed
            printf ("%d\t", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
2       3       5       7       11      13      17      19      23      29
31      37      41      43      47      53      59      61      67      71
73      79      83      89      97      101     103     107     109     113
127     131     137     139     149     151     157     163     167     173
179     181     191     193     197     199     211     223     227     229
233     239     241     251     257     263     269     271     277     281
283     293
```

It's also a rather crude way to figure out primes, but first things first.

Answer (score 1):

Better try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i,j,isPrime;
   for(i=2;i<300;i++)
   {
       isPrime = 1; //Firstly we assume that the number is prime;
       for(j=2;j<i-1;j++) // you can also use i/2 or sqrt(i) for checking
       {
           if(i%j==0)  //This condition only evaluates to true when j is factor of i
           { 
               isPrime = 0; 
               break;  //Now as we have a factor we are sure its not prime,So break the loop;  
           }
       }   
       if(isPrime == 1) printf("%d\t",i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie done, you can edit the answer, if it makes the answer more understandable

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop, you do either a `break` or a `continue`. But this merely `break`s or `continue`s the inner loop, and the `printf` will be executed irrespective of which is chosen. If you'd pasted the code as text, I might have fixed it for you!